# Attributed Text in tableViewCell Crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have a label in a table view cell that I pass some attributed text to using this code:

```
NSString *labelText = [object objectForKey:@"prayerText"];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:25];

[attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];

_prayer.prayerText.attributedText = attributedString;
```

It works fine and dandy at the start of the app and when you tap on that cell it goes to a detail view with essentially the same code to display that text with the same attributes.  The crash occurs when I go back to the table view.  I get this error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'
```

So it seems that `labelText` is deallocating and when the view comes back, before it can populate with data from the data source my attributed string is being initialized with a nil string.

So how do I test this theory and more importantly how do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I fixed it by adding this:

```
if (!labelText || [labelText isEqualToString:@""]) {

        attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

}

else {

    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];

}
```

I should read up on it a bit more but a different method is used to populate the cells when using parse and something weird must be happening with the lifecycle that was throwing that exception but adding the check fixed it.  Its a bit dirty but it works.

Comment: Log the contents of your `object` dictionary to see what is actually in there. It appears there is no value for the key `prayerText` so either the dictionary is getting recreated without it or it is being removed at some point. In any case, the problem does not lie in the code you posted, so you'll need to provide more surrounding code (that modifies the dictionary, and perhaps the view lifecycle).

Comment: @Dima It is in there initially its just when I go to a detail view and then come back that it gives me that nil error

Comment: I understand that but it is not magically happening on its own. Somehow at some point between those 2 points it is getting changed or reset. You need to find any point where either of those 2 things is happening and see which one is getting called when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Dima I did log it when when I go back my log prints null.  So I don't know where it is becoming null.

Comment: What is "object", and where do you set its value?

Comment: `object` is set by the Parse framework.  I am using a `PFQueryTableViewController` and it is set dynamically.

Comment: @Dima I fixed it.  Look at edit

Comment: I should read up on it a bit more but a different method is used to populate the cells when using parse and something weird must be happening with the lifecycle that was throwing that exception but adding the check fixed it.  Its a bit dirty but it works.

Comment: rdelmar is on the right track if you want to fix it properly. With this fix you are just putting a hack in. You need to understand why [object objectForKey:@"prayerText"]; returned nil when it came back. Its not about labelText getting deallocated

Comment: @hackerinheels this is true but this code is needed anyway now that I think about it because the value of that key could very well be null under other circumstances.  Basically people post pictures with text and they have the option of not adding text so that bit would be necessary but I agree that I should look into why it is returning nil under these circumstances